# Adding Two Icon images on right of navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I want to add add two icon images on right side on the navbar.

I am trying this but problem is images are treated just static. they don't adjust themselves dynamically.

I am using bootstrap 3.0., please help me and give the solution.

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/Layout_100.png" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/Layout_33_33_33.png" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```